# "didUpdateLocations" doesn't being called when monitoring significant location changes

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, cocoa-touch, core-location

I'm trying to monitor user's significant location changes using a singleton locationManager called `LocationService`, it goes like that:

**LocationService.Swift**:

```
 class var sharedInstance: LocationService {
        struct Static {
            static var onceToken: dispatch_once_t = 0

            static var instance: LocationService? = nil
        }
        dispatch_once(&Static.onceToken) {
            Static.instance = LocationService()
        }
        return Static.instance!
    }

    var locationManager: CLLocationManager?
    var location: CLLocation?
    var delegate: LocationServiceDelegate?

    override init() {
        super.init()

        self.locationManager = CLLocationManager()
        guard let locationManager = self.locationManager else {
            return
        }

        if CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == .NotDetermined {
            locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
        }

        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.distanceFilter = 10
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        locationManager.pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically = false

        if NSString(string: UIDevice.currentDevice().systemName).floatValue >= 9 {
            locationManager.allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates = true
        }
    }

func startUpdatingLocation() {
        print("Starting Location Updates")
        self.locationManager?.startUpdatingLocation()
    }

func startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges() {
        print("Starting Significant Location Updates")
        self.locationManager?.startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges()
    }

// CLLocationManagerDelegate
    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {

        guard let location = locations.last else {
            return
        }

        // singleton for get last location
        self.location = location
    }
```

**myVC.swift**:

```
private let locationService = LocationService.sharedInstance

func prepareInformation() {
        self.locationService.delegate = self
        self.locationService.startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges()
    }
```

but `didUpdateLocations` being called just one time when the app is launched, and then it doesn't even being called. But when I switch the line:

```
self.locationService.startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges()
```

to:

```
self.locationService.startUpdatingLocation()
```

it works great and called every time the user moves.

what can be the problem? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

According to Apple docs

> After returning a current location fix, the receiver generates update
>   events only when a significant change in the user’s location is
>   detected. **It does not rely on the value in the distanceFilter property**
>   to generate events.

And

> Apps can expect a notification as soon as the device moves 500 meters
>   or more from its previous notification. It should not expect
>   notifications more frequently than once every five minutes. If the
>   device is able to retrieve data from the network, the location manager
>   is much more likely to deliver notifications in a timely manner

I think you are expecting an event when the user changes its location by 10 meters, but this method doesn't depend on distanceFilter. Whoever when you use startUpdatingLocation() you will get events which will depend on distanceFilter property.

You can read more about this [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CLLocationManager/startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges).